# How Can I convert this type of List in to map

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

// this is the list

```
[{welcome_eap: Welcome to Automation Platform}, {eap_version: V2.1.0}, {iot_enable_platform: IOT Enabled Automation Platform}]
```

// i want this type of result
map =

```
{welcome_eap: Welcome to Automation Platform, eap_version: V2.1.0, iot_enable_platform: IOT Enabled Automation Platform}
```

Comment: just access the lists index. If this is always the first index, use `yourList.first` to access the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a new map like this:

```dart
const example = [{"welcome_eap": "Welcome to Automation Platform"}, {"eap_version": "V2.1.0"}, {"iot_enable_platform": "IOT Enabled Automation Platform"}];
final result = {for (final entry in example) entry.keys.first: entry.values.first};
print(result);
```

Comment: Excellent answer, I didn't know `for` can be used in a `map` (I've only used it in a List so far :D, have an upvote!)

Answer (score 0):

In list each map can have multiple entries.

Try this,

```dart
  final dataMap = {};
  
  for(final data in dataList){
    dataMap.addEntries(data.entries);
  }
```